# Triggers - with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

How can I create a trigger that runs before update or insert and checks if the new row has a specific criteria?

Let's say column A has value bigger than 5

thanks.

Comment: create `instead of insert,update` trigger ; inside the trigger body you have access to `inserted` pseudo-table which represent new rows. I guess you need to do some actions if condition is true, not just prevent inserting such records which can be efficiently done with CHECK constraint as MarcinJuraszek pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

> let's say column A has value bigger than 5

It should be done using [`CHECK` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on a table column instead of `TRIGGER`, e.g.:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesHistory](
      (...)
      [A] [int] NULL CHECK (A > 5)
)
```

Comment: maybe to trigger a specific logic after this case

Answer (score 1):

You can use [INSTEAD OF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) trigger

Simple example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER iu_trigger ON [dbo].[SalesHistory]
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM inserted
             WHERE A > 5
             )
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'A > 5'     
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'A <= 5'
  END            
END
```